# %20 and other misc stuff in my dynamic text

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-2

How do I get the html space characters out of my dynamic text loaded from a text file?

This is what my loaded text looks like in my .swf:

```
Adaptasi%20morfologi%20adalah%20penyesuaian%2E%2E%2E%0D%0A%0D%0A=&onLoad=%5Btype%20Function%5D
```

And it's my actionscript:

```
var select_obj:LoadVars = new LoadVars(); 
select_obj.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) { 
    if (success) { 
        isi.text = select_obj;
        trace (select_obj);
    } else { 
      trace('error...');
    } 
}; 

filepath = "http://localhost/adaptasi/";
select_obj.sendAndLoad(filepath + "morfologi.php", select_obj, "GET");
```

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php

mysql_pconnect ("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db ("adaptasi");

$qResult = mysql_query ("SELECT isi FROM materi WHERE id = 1");

$nRows = mysql_num_rows($qResult);

$rString ="";

for ($i=0; $i< $nRows; $i++){

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($qResult);

    $rString .= $row['isi'];

}

echo $rString;

?>
```

Comment: echo $rString; output?

Comment: is it `=` _Adaptasi%20morfologi%20adalah%20penyesuaian%2E%2E%2E%0D%0A%0D%0A=&onLoad=%5Btype%20Function%5D_

Comment: Yes, it is. I wanna erase %20, %2E%2E%2E%, and etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your values sent by your script, you should return them as a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs like this :

```
message=hello&from=user1&to=user2
```

which can be returned by your PHP script :

```
<?php
    echo "message=hello&from=user1&to=user2";
?>
```

then the `LoadVars` object will decode (parse) that variable string automatically for you as properties of the `LoadVars` object :

```
var result:LoadVars = new LoadVars(); 
    result.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
        if (success) {
            trace(result.message);  // gives : hello
            trace(result.from);     // gives : user1
            trace(result.to);       // gives : user2
            trace(result);          // gives : to=user2&from=user1&message=hello&onLoad=%5Btype%20Function%5D
        } else {
            trace('error !');
        }
    };
    result.sendAndLoad(filepath, result);
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: @CandraHerk `message` here is a variable returned inside the PHP's response : `echo "message=hello&from=user1&to=user2" ; `.

Comment: I just want to erase %20 and etc. How to I write my action script?

Comment: var result:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

var filepath:String;

result.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) { 
    if (success) { 
        text_morfo.text = result;
  trace (result.unescape);
  trace("success route");
    } else { 
      trace('error...');
    } 
}; 

filepath = "http://localhost/adaptasi/";
result.sendAndLoad(filepath + "morfologi.php", result, "GET");

Comment: @CandraHerk Did you read my answer ?! You have to change also your PHP code ... please read my answer and test it and you will understand what you should change to your code ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97112/discussion-between-candra-herk-and-akmozo).

Comment: Great answer, Thanks Akmozo.

Comment: @CandraHerk, you should also upvote useful answers (and accept some for your other previous questions).

Comment: hello @akmozo can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171467/result-update-database-from-flash?noredirect=1#comment56092275_34171467

Answer (score 1):

Use [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function:

```
<?PHP
$string = "Adaptasi%20morfologi%20adalah%20penyesuaian%2E%2E%2E%0D%0A%0D%0A=&onLoad=%5Btype%20Function%5D";
//$string = $_GET['variable'];
$rString = urldecode($string);
echo $rString;
```

Comment: It's clear from your answer that you didn't know ActionScript or what that AS script do. The mentioned string is the returned result in the AS side and not in the PHP one, so OP should parse (decode) it in the AS side to get the desired result after putting it in the correct way in the PHP script of course.

Comment: +1. As Akmozo stated the fix on the ActionScript side however you were useful in suggesting to decode the string result (just not in the PHP side).

Answer (score 1):

> I wanna erase %20, %2E%2E%2E%, and etc..

For that you can try either **[decodeURIComponent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#decodeURIComponent())**  or just **[decodeURI](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#decodeURI())**. Read that manual for differences (but for your current result, any of these two is good).

An example with your code :

```
var result:LoadVars = new LoadVars(); 
var filepath:String;

filepath = "localhost/adaptasi/"; 
result.sendAndLoad(filepath + "morfologi.php", result, "GET");

result.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) 
{ 
    if ( success ) 
    {   
        text_morfo.text = result; 
        text_morfo = decodeURIComponent( text_morfo );

        trace("success route : "); trace( text_morfo );   
    } 
    else { trace("error in result..."); } 
}
```

Also I don't know what else your AS & PHP code will add later so if you need a quick testing tool you can try **[this link](http://www.adrianparr.com/?p=142)**. Just put your traced results into the bottom box and choose option (like **unescape**, **decodeURI** etc). This will quickly help you see which command is best to use in your AS code.