# Result Update Database from Flash

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-2

I want to update database with flash (text input)

Here is my php code

```
<?php

    mysql_pconnect ("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db ("adaptasi");

    $isi = isset($_POST['OutData']);

    $query2 = "UPDATE materi SET isi='$isi' WHERE id = 1";

    $result2=mysql_query($query2) or die("Query Failed : ".mysql_error());

?>
```

Here is my Actionscript 2

```
function SubmitData() 
{ 
    trace("Sending"); 

    var OutData = new LoadVars(); 
    text_morfologi.text = OutData.OutData; 

    filepath = "http://localhost/adaptasi/";
    OutData.sendAndLoad(filepath + "editmorfologi.php", OutData, "POST");

} 

btnsave.onRelease = function() 
{ 
    SubmitData(); 
    btnedit.visible = true;
    btnsave.visible = false;
};
```

But the result isi in database is '1' not the text that I input in the text field.
Thanks

Comment: Well, you're setting `$isi = isset($_POST['OutData']);` which would be a boolean being converted to 1 as a string for `true`

Comment: Are you getting $_POST['OutData'] as text??

Comment: How can I get the string? @tigrang

Comment: Yes, Krishna... I've wrote $isi = $_POST['OutData']; It's return 'undefined'

Comment: dear isset($_POST['OutData']) is worked like a condition so it'll return true or false. So you must need to do concatenation of other fields name within $isi

Comment: @KrishnaGupta How the source code $isi must be like?

Comment: You were have some input fields in your form??

Comment: @KrishnaGupta Yes, I have and the name is text_morfologi

Comment: Then hold $isi = isset($_POST['OutData']) ? $_POST['text_morfologi'] : '';

Comment: It's not work @KrishnaGupta . and the result is 'Undefined'

Comment: That means you are not getting form values so check your form attributes properly...

Comment: I change that to var OutData = new LoadVars(); 
    text_morfologi.text = OutData.OutData; but the result still undefined. @KrishnaGupta

Comment: OutData.sendAndLoad(filepath + "editmorfologi.php", OutData, "POST");

Comment: Hello @akmozo can you help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171467/result-update-database-from-flash?noredirect=1#comment56092275_34171467

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems in your code :

**ActionScript 2 :**

To send data using a [`LoadVars`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001161.html) object you have to attache it to that object as its properties, and if you want to receive a response from your server side script, you can use [`LoadVars.sendAndLoad()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001174.html) but if you want just to send that data without waiting for any response, you can use [`LoadVars.send()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001173.html).

Supposed that you will use `sendAndLoad()` function, so you code can be like this :

```
var url:String = 'http://www.example.com/update.php';

// the LoadVars object that will receive (load) a response from the server
var receiver:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
    receiver.onLoad = function(success:Boolean)
    {
        if (success) {
            trace(receiver.response);    // gives for example : update successful
        } else {
            trace('error');
        }
    }

// the LoadVars object which will send (post) some data to the server
var sender:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
    sender.id = txt_id.text;
    sender.name = txt_name.text;
    sender.sendAndLoad(url, receiver);    // we don't set the method to POST because that's its default value
```

**PHP :**

As mentioned in many comments, the PHP's [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function is used to verify if a variable is set and is not NULL and it returns a boolean value ( `TRUE` of `FALSE` ) which is when it's [casting (converting) to a string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) will give you `1` for `TRUE` and `` (empty string) for `FALSE`.

In your case, and according to you, I think that as the the variable `$_POST['OutData']` is apparently set, `isset($_POST['OutData'])` is true which will set the value of `$isi` to `1`, so you will get :

```
$query2 = "UPDATE materi SET isi='1' WHERE id = 1";
```

but according to your posted code, I think that you should get :

```
$query2 = "UPDATE materi SET isi='' WHERE id = 1";
```

Returning now to our current example, we will get our two POST variables (id, and name) sent by the AS2 script to update the DB and then return a response if the data has been successfully updated or not :

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['id'] && isset($_POST['name']))
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];    

        mysql_pconnect('localhost', 'root', '');
        mysql_select_db('my_db');

        $query = "UPDATE users SET name = '$name' WHERE id = $id";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if($result){
            echo 'response=update successful';
        } else {
            echo 'response=update failed';
        }
    }

?>
```

---

Of course here I tried just to give you a very simple example of a working code according to your current one. You should know that for your PHP side that the "mysql" extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and was removed in PHP 7, so you should think to use ["mysqli"](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or ["PDO"](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions, for more about that, take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), also don't forget to [sanitize](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php), [validate](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) and [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) any user's data, ... and  for the ActionScript side, maybe it's the time to start [learning ActionScript 3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html) ...

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks @akmozo You're the great one, It's totally work for real.